# How to access ActiveModel attributes from a method call on the class?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to reference `user#role` to define an association in a module.  I've tried with a block as shown below, but that doesn't work. How does Rails implement behavior like this?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Profile
  has_profile { |user| { class_name: "#{user.role}::Profile" }}
end

module Profile
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods

    def has_profile(&block)

      role = ### How to access #role ? ###

      class_eval do
        has_one :profile, class_name: "#{role}::Profile"
      end
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do something like this. I didn't tested and I'm just supposing you can do this kind of stuff

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Profile
  has_profile { |user| user.role }
end

module Profile
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do  
    after_initialize :_init_profile
  end

  def _init_profile
    role = @_role_block.call(self)
    # Here we do class eval on singleton so we dont change base class
    # I'm not sure if this works as it is but should be close enought
    class << self; self; end.class_eval do
      has_one :profile, class_name: "#{role}::Profile"
    end
  end


  module ClassMethods

    def has_profile(&block)
      @_role_block = block
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
module Models
  module Profile
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      after_initialize :_init_profile
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def has_profile(&block)
        @profile_association_block = block
      end
    end

    def _init_profile
      block = self.class.instance_variable_get :@profile_association_block
      self.class.has_one :profile, block.call(self)
    end
```